# Can we use an automation tool to test the text file created by Java?if yes which one?There is no UI for this project

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework

Can we use an automation tool to test the text file created by Java?if yes which one?

The data will be loaded in the oracle DB and then we have to create a text file using that data after applying logic developed in java. There is no UI for this project.

**background.**

Our client is pharmacy company. They want a report to be generated for a certain type of drugs whenever they are sold. In the report we have to provide the prescriber information, store level detail,patient detail,date etc

Comment: Yes, it is very possible and it is a common practice. But without further details, it is hard to make a recommendation here.

Comment: @YuZhang Thanks for your response.Can you please let me know what all details do you need?

Comment: What are your testing scopes? What are your business rules?

Comment: @YuZhang..I will give you little background.Our client is pharmacy company.They want a report to be generated for a certain type of drugs whenever they are sold.In the report we have to provide the prescriber information, store level detail,patient detail,date etc..

Comment: There is no tool that you can directly use, but you can code a test case in any language of your choosing. Simply read this generated file, parse it, compare it against a known reference.

Comment: The created file is a simple text file, not a PDF, right?

Comment: @beatngu13 yes it is just a simple text file..

Comment: Agree with @Vishal Aggarwal.
You can write simple unit tests to verify this.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a good use case for [Golden Master Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/characterization-testing/info):

> [Characterization Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_test) (aka Golden Master Testing) is a means to characterize the behavior of the test object to protect it against unintended changes, regardless of its correctness. In order to do so, the results of a previous (typically stable) version—the golden master—serve as the oracle for the tests (also known as [consistency oracle](http://www.softwarequalitymethods.com/Papers/OracleTax.pdf) since it compares the consistency between two versions).

If you also write your tests in Java, you can use [Approval Tests](http://approvaltests.com/) (which also has ports for C#, Python, JavaScript etc.). It will help to create, manage, and compare the golden master—in your case the created text file. Afterwards, your test(s) will be as simple as this (`readFileToString` is from [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/)):

```
String fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("path/to/file"));
Approvals.verify(fileContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, all you need is a programming language and test logic.

Do you have any specific problem implementing your test algorithm?

Comment: as simple as that, no need for fancy tooling

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) tool, it is free and open source so there are no any costs and it has everything you need, to wit:

1. [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler to fetch the data from Oracle database
2. [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to fetch the data from the text file on a file system (use `file` as "protocol")
3. [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) - to verify the integrity of data in DB and in the file.

JMeter [User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html) and [JMeter Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/jmeter-tutorial) should help you to get started very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it should start at the unit test layer of the test pyramid, then perhaps a simple integration test (if one doesn't already exist) to assert the mocked data from the db is returned as expected in the unit test.